# Unable to convert Ansible playbook memcached (working) to docker-compose memcached (failing)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, dockerfile

I have memcached service provisioned with Ansible which is working fine, now i would like to containerize memcached service, but it fail with

> error.EMERGENCY: An exception was raised while creating "AbcRedirect\Redirector"; no instance returned {"exception":"[object] (Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException(code: 0): An exception was raised while creating "AbcRedirect\Redirector"; no instance returned at /srv/www/xxxxxxx/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:941, Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException(code: 0): An exception was raised while creating "xxxxx\Redirect\Strategy\ThemeStrategy"; no instance returned at /srv/www/xxxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:941, Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException(code: 0): An exception was raised while creating "xxxxxxx\Service\ThemeErpUrlService"; no instance returned at /srv/www/xxxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:941, Zend\Cache\Exception\RuntimeException(code: 0): SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY at /srv/www/xxxxxxxxx/vendor/zendframework/zend-cache/src/Storage/Adapter/Memcached.php:651)"} {"file":"/srv/www/xxxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/xxx/xxxx-bootstrap/src/Module.php","line":71,"class":"xxxx\Bootstrap\Module","function":"xxx\Bootstrap{closure}","cli":false,"host":"en-xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx","uri":"/","user_ip":"172.100.0.1","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","request_method":"GET"}

Working Ansible task:

```
---
# Install Memcached
- name: ensure Memcached is installed
  yum:
    name:
      - memcached
    state: present
  become: yes

# Configure Memcached
- name: configure Memcached
  template:
    src: memcached.conf.j2
    dest: "{{ memcached_config_file }}"
  notify: restart memcached
  become: yes

# Enable on boot
- name: ensure Memcached is started and enabled on boot
  service:
    name: memcached
    state: started

  become: yes
```

Non working Docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  xxxx-dev:
    image: centos7
    container_name: dev-app
    hostname: dev
    volumes:
      - dev-app-nfsmount:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR}
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    privileged: true
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.2
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 6082:6082
      - 9001:9001
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
      - 29015:29015
    extra_hosts:
      - dev-app:127.0.0.1
      - dev-memcached:172.100.0.9

---------------------
-----------------------
-----------------------

 dev-memcached:
    image: memcached
    container_name: dev-memcached
    hostname: dev-memcached
    user: "${V_UID}:${V_GID}"
    volumes:
      - dev-nfsmount-memcached:${CONTAINER_MOUNT_DIR_MEMCACHED}
    networks:
      dev-online:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.0.9
    ports:
      - 11211:11211
    extra_hosts:
      - dev-app:172.100.0.2
      - dev-memcached:127.0.0.1
```

I tried to change 127.0.0.1 to Memcached container name(dev-memcached), but not success

```
 if (extension_loaded('memcached')) {
            $memcached = new \Memcached();
            $memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

            $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache();
            $cache->setMemcached($memcached);

            return $cache;
        }
```

Comment: Compose [provides a network environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for you.  `localhost` is generally "the current container" in Docker, so you need to use the Compose service name `dev-memcached` as a host name (consider making this configurable in an environment variable).  I'd recommend deleting all of the `networks:` and especially `extra_hosts:` blocks to use the default Compose networking setup, which will work fine.

Comment: you mean, i need to replace addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211); to addServer('dev-memcached', 11211); ? that i already tried and no success, coming to extra hosts, i am not allowed to touch them, as they are working fine, with other containers.